# How to insert values in STL map within a loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, stl, coding-style

I wanted to know how one can insert values in map within a loop.
I had used `insert()` in the following code but this did not worked.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while (t--)
    {
        int n, i;
        map<char*, int> vote;
        char name[20], v;
        scanf("%d", &n);
        for (i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        {
            scanf("%s %c", name, &v);
            vote.insert(make_pair(name, 0));

            vote[name] = 0;
            if (v == '+')
                vote[name]++;
            else
                vote[name]--;
            printf("%d\n", vote[name]);
            printf("Size=%lu\n", vote.size());
        }
        int score = 0;
        for (map<char*, int>::iterator it = vote.begin(); it != vote.end(); ++it)
        {
            printf("%s%d\n", it->first, it->second);
            score += it->second;
        }
        printf("%d\n", score);

    }
}
```

Everytime I type a new key(string) it just updates the previous one.
The size of the map is always 1.

How do I correctly add a new element to the map?

Comment: Put your code in your post instead of linking it

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum No the OP's supposed to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that's an essentially bit more, than just posting their code.

Comment: One issue at a time, the linked code isn't exceptionally long

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: You reset the name count right back to 0 again here:  `vote[name] = 0;`  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Want to explain the edit reversion?

Comment: That is **not** a valid reason to revert an edit.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Arguable. I gave enough hints how the OP should improve their question. And as mentioned _just posting the code_ isn't an improvement.

Comment: Spare me your righteous BS. Reverting an edit simply because the original poster wasn't the one who made it is not a valid reason.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ a question with code is better than a question with no code . Further, site policy is that the code should be in the question, not externally linked. So by making your edit to move the code from the question to an external site, you are violating site policy. And who are you to demand that a question retain its original appearance? If you don't like this question, vote on it and move on.

Comment: @MattMcNabb And who are you, thinking there's actually need to remind me _who I am_??

Comment: Rolled back again, let's see.

Comment: @MattMcNabb So please get your helping hands on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830789/csegmentation-fault) now! No trolling ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ downvoted, VTC & moved on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map is keyed by a pointer (`char*`). The key in your code is always the same one - the `name` pointer (Although you change the content that the pointer points on, it does not change the fact that the pointer itself is not the same).

You can use `std::string` as a key instead of the `char*`.

Changing the definition of the map (replace `char*` in `std::string`) would fix the problem.

EDIT: As @McNabb said, also change `it->first` to `it->first.c_str()`.

Comment: Don't _guess_, be sure with answers.

Comment: upvoted, this clearly solves OP's problem. Don't listen to the trolls .

Comment: Getting back on topic, OP would also need to use `it->first.c_str()` in the `printf` statement

Comment: Thanks. I was pretty sure what the problem was. The "guess" was just about the amount of changes needed to be performed which is not the main part of the answer. I removed the "I guess..." words and added @McNabb's addition so the answer would not be misleading.